# Symfony 6.2 MapEntity to use custom finder?

Tags: php, symfony

I have two databases, **MYSQL** and **MongoDB**, as **MongoDB** works with **Documents** I need a way to fetch data from MongoDB using **in-URL parameters**. **Sensio/Framework-Extra-Bundle** had this feature, but its going to be abandoned and I decided to switch on **Symfony Attributes** instead.

With **Sensio/Framework-Extra-Bundle** **#[ParamConverter]** that would look something like this:

```
#[Route('/{slug}', methods: ['GET'])]
#[ParamConverter('slug', options: ['finder' => 'CustomFinder', 'attributes' => ['id']])]
```

Since they switched over to **Symfony Attributes** and now they are using **#[MapEntity]** I'm not sure this is possible anymore.

I have tried to do similar with **#[MapEntity]** like this:

```
#[MapEntity(mapping: ['finder' => 'CustomFinder', 'slug' => 'id'])] MyDocument $document
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: App\Controller\MyController::get(): Argument #1 ($document) must be of type App\Document\MyDocument, string given, called in /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php on line 163
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#[MapEntity(mapping: ['finder' => 'CustomFinder', 'id' => 'slug'])] MyDocument $document
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Seems like after they migrated Attributes from SensioFrameworkExtraBundle they forgot to implement support for MongoDB. Thanks for taking time to answer! :)